# Distributing intersection over vector space addition.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $U, S, W$ be three subspaces of the vector space $V$. Prove or disprove the following
>
> a) $U ∩ (S+W) ⊆ (U ∩ S) + (U ∩ W)$
>
> b) $(U ∩ S) + W ⊆ (U + W) ∩ (S + W)$

**My Approach:**

Let $v ∈ U ∩ (S + W) \implies v ∈ U \wedge v ∈ (S + W)$. Now I have to show that $v = x + y$ such that $x ∈ (U ∩ S)$ and $y ∈ (U ∩ W)$. I can't think of any way to express $v$ in this form.

Comment: I do not either.

Comment: At first look, your comment looks like spam.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @StabReberie If by "spam" you mean something you don't like, then perhaps. If by "spam" you mean vexatory or unwanted advertisement of a product by digital means, then perhaps no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

b) follows easily from definition: let $z \in (U\cap S)+W$. Then $z=x+y$ with $x \in (U\cap S)$ and $y \in W$. Since $x \in U$ we get $z \in U+W$. Similarly we have $ z \in  S+W$. This proves b).

a) is false. Take $S$ to be the x-axis and $W$ the y-axis. If $U$ is the line $\{(x,y): y=x\}$ then LHS is $U$ and RHS is $\{0\}$.

Comment: Definition of what? Could you elaborate?

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: I think I figured it out, let $x ∈ (U∩S) + W$, thus $x$ is a linear combination of elements from $W$ and elements common to $U$ and $S$. This implies that $x$ is a linear combination of elements from $U$ and $W$ i.e $x ∈ (U+W)$. Similarly $x ∈ (S+W)$, and we're done. **Could anyone help me write this more formally, using standard notations?**